# x86-64 order of passing parameters in registers

Tags: c, assembly, parameters, x86-64, calling-convention

I'm curious about the parameter passing procedure in the x86-64 environment and therefore I wrote a snippet of code.

```
//a.c
extern int shared;
int main(){
    int a=100;
    swap(&a, &shared);
}
//b.c
int shared=1;
void swap(int* a, int* b){
    *a ^= *b ^= *a ^= *b;
}
```

I compile two files using the following commands:
`gcc -c -fno-stack-protector a.c b.c`
Then I `objdump -d a.o` to check a.o's disassembly code.

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
   8:   c7 45 fc 64 00 00 00    movl   $0x64,-0x4(%rbp)
   f:   48 8d 45 fc             lea    -0x4(%rbp),%rax
  13:   be 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%esi
  18:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  1b:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  20:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  25 <main+0x25>
  25:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  2a:   c9                      leaveq 
  2b:   c3                      retq
```

Due to my working environment is **Ubuntu 16.04 x86-64**, I found it hard to understand the order of passing parameter.

In my point of view, the default call convention is `fastcall` here and therefore the parameters are passed from **right to left**.

I know from the x86-64 System V ABI manual that `rdi` and `rsi` are used for passing the first two parameters [image]

However, according to the disassembly code, `rdi` is responsible for `var a`, which is the param on the left, meaning it should be the **second** param.

Could someone help me point out my mistake?

Comment: The parameter on the left is the first parameter.

Comment: The x86-64 System V is not `fastcall`.  It doesn't have a name other than Sys V.  That term describes the Windows calling convention.

Comment: Please specify which compiler version and switches are in use

Comment: @M.M: Ubuntu 16.04 has gcc5.3 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/gcc), and the OP specified that it was compiled with `gcc -c -fno-stack-protector a.c b.c`.  IDK why you're asking, though; this is all perfectly normal `-O0` un-optimized compiler output, and should be essentially the same on literally any x86-64 gcc version, except a gcc built with `--enable-default-pie` will use `lea shared(%rip), %rsi`.  (Not the case for Ubuntu 16.04, apparently.)

Comment: @PeterCordes whether we're in C89 mode or not affects the behaviour of calling an undeclared function

Comment: @M.M: In my experience, gcc defines the behaviour even in C99/C11 mode, by applying the C89 arg promotion rules.  (And treating it as variadic for setting AL). https://godbolt.org/z/41dfgG with or without optimization enabled, gcc5.3 zeros EAX, even with `-std=c11`  (not `gnu11`).  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/PowerPC-SPE-Options.html#index-mno-prototype says that PowerPC gcc has a `-mprototype` option to promise that calls to variadic functions are properly prototyped, so it can avoid the PPC equivalent (clearing/setting a bit in CR) before unprototyped calls.  Doesn't mention C89-only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Args are numbered from left to right** (credit to @R. for spotting that this was your actual confusion; I thought you were talking about the order of asm instructions, and missed the last paragraph of the question.)

Looks normal to me.  When the `call swap` instruction runs,

- `rdi` holds a pointer to `a` (a local on the stack), set up by
  `lea  -0x4(%rbp),%rax` and `mov   %rax,%rdi`.

  (instead of just `lea` into `rdi`, because you didn't enable optimization.)
- `rsi` holds a pointer to `shared`, set up by `mov $shared,%esi`
- `al` holds `0` because you didn't define or prototype the function before calling it.  (gcc should have warned you about this even without `-Wall`)

The disassembly of the `.o` shows `$shared` as 0 because it's not linked yet, so it's a placeholder (and 0 offset) from the symbol.  Use `objdump -drwC` to see relocation symbols.  (I like `-Mintel` as well, instead of AT&T syntax.)

Also easier to look at would be the compiler's asm output, where you would see `$shared` instead of a number and symbol reference.  See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output).

---

**It doesn't matter what order registers are written, only their value on entry to the called function.**

Same for stack args: if a compiler chooses to use `mov` to write args to the stack, it can do it in any order.

Only if you choose to use `push` do you have to go from right to left to leave the first (left-most) arg at the lowest address, as required by all the mainstream C calling conventions for args that aren't passed in registers (if any).

This right-to-left order might be why `gcc -O0` (no optimization, plus anti-optimization for debugging) chooses to set registers in that order, even though it doesn't matter.

---

And BTW, xor-swap is useless and pointless even if implemented correctly without UB.  ([Are there sequence points in the expression a^=b^=a^=b, or is it undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475166/are-there-sequence-points-in-the-expression-a-b-a-b-or-is-it-undefined)).

`if(a==b) { *a = *b = 0; } else { int tmp = *a; *a=*b; *b=tmp; }` is a more efficient swap that preserves the behaviour of a safe xor-swap of zeroing if both pointers are to the same object.  I assume you want that?  Why else would you use an xor-swap?

The compiler-generated asm for either will basically suck if you don't enable optimization, just like the code for `main` sucks for the same reason.  And if you do, `swap` can often inline and be zero instructions, or just cost up to 3 `mov` instructions between registers; sometimes less.  (The compiler can just change its register allocation and decide that `a` and `b` are in opposite registers now.)

Comment: What do you mean by UB sir

Comment: @BecomeBetter  [What Every Programmer Should Know about *Undefined Behaviour*](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).  See also: 
 [Undefined behaviour of operators in XOR swap algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28782068) for exactly what's wrong with your `swap` function, that question uses the same definition.

Answer (score 3):

Your idea of first/second is wrong. Counting starts from the left.

In addition your code has some problems, at least:

1. You're calling `swap` without a declaration/prototype, so while doesn't have to, GCC has opted to generate code that would work if it were a variadic function (storing 0 in `%rax`).
2. The definition of `swap` is a heap of undefined behavior.